# Swift protocol with associatedtype as a parameter type

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

So here I have this protocol

```
public protocol UseCase {

    associatedtype ResponseType
    associatedtype Parameters

    func build(params: Parameters) -> Single<ResponseType>

}

public extension UseCase {

    func execute(params: Parameters) -> Single<ResponseType> {
        return build(params: params)
                .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: DispatchQoS.background))
                .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    }

}
```

And I have a Struct that implement the `UseCase` protocol like this

```
public struct CreateNewAccount: UseCase {

    private let repository: AuthRepository

    public init(repository: AuthRepository) {
        self.repository = repository
    }

    public func build(params: Params) -> Single<User> {
        return repository.register(params: params)
    }

    public struct Params: RequestParams {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want to use this `CreateNewAccount` on another class, but I don't want to directly use `CreateNewAccount` and I want to pass it as a `UseCase` instead, because since It's a protocol It can be easily mocked for testing.
But when I do something like this

```
class RegisterViewModel: ViewModel {

    private let createNewAccount: UseCase // Error on this line

    init(createNewAccount: UseCase) { // Error on this line
        self.createNewAccount = createNewAccount
    }
}
```

That gave me an error like this

```
Error:(34, 35) protocol 'UseCase' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

So, is there's something that I can change from my code to make this kind of case works? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use protocols with associated type as a field.

You have to use them only as an implementation of classes. In most cases, those classes should are generic.

For instance, this code is allowed:

```swift
public struct CreateNewAccount<T, K>: UseCase {
    public typealias ResponseType = T
    public typealias Parameters = K
}
```

and so,

```swift
private let createNewAccount: CreateNewAccount<YouClass1,YouClass2>
```

or wrap it somehow by another protocol.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So that's mean that I must use `CreateNewAccount` directly on its consumer? Do you have another idea to counter this case? So I can pass the abstract (protocol) type to the consumer instead of the concrete implementation.

Comment: as I know, the only solution is to use another protocol if you want to use only protocols. `public struct CreateNewAccount<T, K>: UseCase, YourNewSimpleProtocol`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179